# R: expand.grid with the same vector repeated multiple times

Tags: r, vector, combinations

So I'm trying to get all the possible combinations of rolling two dice `n` number of times.
Currently I have:

```
# Get all possible rolls with two dice
d <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
rolls <- lapply(apply(expand.grid(d, d), 1, identity), unlist)

# Get all possible ways to roll two dice twice
trials <-lapply(apply(expand.grid(rolls, rolls), 1, identity), unlist)
```

`d` stores all possible values you can get on a single dice. `rolls` stores all possible outcomes of rolling two dice at the same time. And `trials` stores all possible outcomes of rolling two dice at the same time, twice in a row.

I can modify the last line as

```
trials <-lapply(apply(expand.grid(rolls, rolls, rolls), 1, identity), unlist)
```

to get all possible outcomes of rolling two dice at the same time, three times in a row, but I cannot figure out how to make the number of times variable, so that I could pass some arbitrary number `n` and get all possible outcomes of rolling two dice at the same time, an `n` number of times in a row

Comment: Try `Rdice::dice.combinations(faces, dice, rolls)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want permutations (both 1,2 and 2, 1) and not combinations (just 1,2), this is simpler:

```
n <- 2
perms <- expand.grid(as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, 6, n)))
dim(perms)
# [1] 36  2
n <- 4
perms <- expand.grid(as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, 6, n)))
dim(perms)
#[1] 1296    4
n <- 6
perms <- expand.grid(as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, 6, n)))
dim(perms)
# [1] 46656     6
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I only made this post about 20 minutes ago but I actually already managed to figure it out. The solution is:

```
trials <-lapply(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(rolls), times = n)), 1, identity), unlist)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).